# Bar chart with two sets of labels in Quickchart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, quickchart

I am trying to create a bar chart for tracking a budget with [quickchart](https://quickchart.io/). I want the chart to have one set of labels on top of the bars (for % remaining), and a second set of labels inside each bar (for $'s remaining).

I was able to figure out the labels on top of the bars, but need help adding a second set of labels within the bars. The labels within the bars will need to be based on a second array of data.

I have posted my code, which can be tweaked in the live editor [here](https://quickchart.io/). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
{
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Food', 'Gas', 'Other'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Category',
      data: [.5, .7, .8]
    }]
  },
  options: {
        plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: function(value) {
            return Math.round(value*100) + '%';},
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'end',
        color: 'black',
        labels: {
          percent: {
            font: {
              weight: 'bold',
              size:26,
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [ {
        type: 'linear',
        ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            suggestedMin : 0,
            suggestedMax : 1,
            }
        }]
      } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside `datalabels.labels.percent`, you could also define `datalabels.labels.value`, both with specific `formatter` and positioning. No need to define a second `dataset`, simply define `amountRemaining` inside the existing dataset and reference it in the corresponding `formatter`.

This could look as follows...

```
{
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['Food', 'Gas', 'Other'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Category',
      data: [.5, .7, .8],
      amountRemaining: [300, 420, 480]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: 'black',
        labels: {
          percent: {
            formatter: v => Math.round(v * 100) + '%',
            anchor: 'end',
            align: 'end',
            font: {
              weight: 'bold',
              size: 26,
            }
          },
          value: {
            formatter: (v, ctx) => ctx.chart.data.datasets[0].amountRemaining[ctx.dataIndex] + '$',
            font: {
              weight: 'bold',
              size: 26,
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        type: 'linear',
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          suggestedMin: 0,
          suggestedMax: 1,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```